# Is there a way to get OneNote to automatically hide done tasks?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

I've been using OneNote as a to do list and it's been pretty good. However, the problem I have is that I have to do a bit of maintenance occassionally, because I have to manually delete the tasks that I have done.

Is there a way for OneNote to move it to the bottom of the list, or to hide or archive done tasks?